# Using sample_weight param with XGBoost through a pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, xgboost

I want to use the `sample_weight` parameter with XGBClassifier from the `xgboost` package.

The problem happen when I want to use it inside a `pipeline` from `sklearn.pipeline`.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.pipeline      import Pipeline
from xgboost  import XGBClassifier

clf = XGBClassifier(**params)
steps = [ ('scaler', MinMaxScaler() ), ('classifier', clf ) ]
    
pipeline = Pipeline( steps )
```

When I run `pipeline.fit(x, y, sample_weight=sample_weight)` where `sample_weight` is just a dictionary with int representing weights, I have the following error:

> ValueError: Pipeline.fit does not accept the sample_weight parameter.

How can I solve this problem? Is there a workaround? I have seen that an [issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/18159) already exists.

Answer (score 2):

The value error message is factually correct - the `Pipeline` class does not contain any business logic dealing with sample weights.

However, your pipeline has two steps. And one of the step components - the XGBoost classifier - supports sample weights.

So, the solution is to address the sample weights parameter directly to the `classifier` step. According to Scikit-Learn conventions, you can do so by prepending the `classifier__` prefix (reads "classifier" plus two underscore characters) to your fit param name.

In short:

```py
pipeline = Pipeline( steps )
pipeline.fit(X, y, classifier__sample_weights = weights)
```

Comment: I have this: `WARNING: /home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/xgboost-split_1667414521300/work/src/learner.cc:767: 
Parameters: { "sample_weight" } are not used.`